# Sum multiple columns that have specific name in columns

Tags: r, sum

I would like to sum the values of `Var1` and `Var2` for each row and produce a new column titled `Vars` which gives the total of `Var1` and `Var2`. I would then like to do the same for `Col1` and `Col2` and have a new column titled `Cols` which gives the sum of `Col1` and `Col2`. How do I write the code for this? Thanks in advance.

```
         df             
         ID Var1    Var2    Col1    Col2
         1    34      22      34      24
         2     3      25      54      65
         3    87      68      14      78
         4    66      98      98     100
         5    55      13      77       2
```

Expected outcome would be the following:

```
          df                        
          ID    Var1    Var2    Col1    Col2    Vars    Cols
          1     34      22      34      24      56      58
          2     3       25      54      65      28      119
          3     87      68      14      78      155     92
          4     66      98      98      100     164     198
          5     55      13      77      2       68      79
```

Comment: This should get you started: `df$Vars <- df$Var1 + df$Var2`

Comment: Pretty sure there will be a duplicate question + answers that covers this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another `dplyr` way is to use helper functions `starts_with` to select columns and then use `rowSums` to sum those columns.

```
library(dplyr)

df$Vars <- df %>%  select(starts_with("Var")) %>%  rowSums()
df$Cols <-  df %>%  select(starts_with("Col")) %>%  rowSums()

df
#  ID Var1 Var2 Col1 Col2 Vars Cols
#1  1   34   22   34   24   56   58
#2  2    3   25   54   65   28  119
#3  3   87   68   14   78  155   92
#4  4   66   98   98  100  164  198
#5  5   55   13   77    2   68   79
```

Comment: Thank you to everyone for their feedback. Ronak, this is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you very much for this.

Comment: @AlexP glad, it helped. You can consider to accept the answer by clicking on the check mark next to vote button.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that column `ID` is irrelevant (no groups) and you are happy to specify column names (solution hard-coded, not generic).

A base R solution:

```
df$Vars <- rowSums(df1[, c("Var1", "Var2")])
df$Cols <- rowSums(df1[, c("Col1", "Col2")])
```

A tidyverse solution:

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

df %>% mutate(Vars = map2_int(Var1, Var2, sum),
              Cols = map2_int(Col1, Col2, sum))

# or just
df %>% mutate(Vars = Var1 + Var2,
              Cols = Col1 + Col2)
```

Comment: Since there is a clear pattern to the input and output columns, it's easy to extend this too: `cols <- c("Var","Col"); df[paste0(cols,"s")] <- lapply(cols, function(x) rowSums(df[grepl(x,names(df))]))`

Answer (score 2):

There are many different ways to do this. With

```
library(dplyr)
df = df %>% #input dataframe
  group_by(ID) %>% #do it for every ID, so every row
  mutate( #add columns to the data frame
    Vars = Var1 + Var2, #do the calculation
    Cols = Col1 + Col2
   )
```

But there are many other ways, eg with apply-functions etc. I suggest to read about the tidyverse.

Answer (score 0):

A solution summing up all columns witch have the same name and end with numbers using `gsub` in *base*:

```
tt <- paste0(gsub('[[:digit:]]+', '', names(df)[-1]),"s")
df <- cbind(df, sapply(unique(tt), function(x) {rowSums(df[grep(x, tt)+1])}))
df
#  ID Var1 Var2 Col1 Col2 Vars Cols
#1  1   34   22   34   24   56   58
#2  2    3   25   54   65   28  119
#3  3   87   68   14   78  155   92
#4  4   66   98   98  100  164  198
#5  5   55   13   77    2   68   79
```

Or an even more general solution:

```
idx <- grep('[[:digit:]]',  names(df))
tt <- paste0(gsub('[[:digit:]]+', '', names(df)[idx]),"s")
df <- cbind(df, sapply(unique(tt), function(x) {rowSums(df[idx[grep(x, tt)]])}))
```